# "Build Raster Attribute Table" tool isn't working (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: gis, raster, arcgis

I have to make an attribute table for a raster file that doesn't have one. The file is a 16 bit signed type and has only 1 band.

The tool "Build Raster Attribute Table" isn't working.

I've opened the tool. In the "Input Raster" dropdown menu, I've chosen the file I want to put an attribute table into. I check "Overwrite". (I've also tried not checking this).

After I run the tool, I right-click the file, the "Attribute table" button is greyed out, suggesting that the attribute table wasn't made.

No error messages show up. It just says "Succeeded".

I also tried running this same tool in Model Builder, but no luck.

The tool also doesn't work for any other raster files that I test it on. All these other raster files that I've tested it on are not large, have 16 bit type, and 1 band. I've tried it on .tiff files and .dem files.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I also have QGIS, so am open to QGIS solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was able to fix it by simply removing the layer from my map and then adding it back in. I guess ArcPro just needed to refresh the layer.